# c++ How to close PDF file using TerminateProcess and handle of child process

Tags: c++, pdf, shellexecute

I want to close a pdf file from my c++ application.
I use ShellExecuteEx to open pdf file, and I catch the handle of the process.

```
std::string s = "myfile.pdf";
std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(s.begin(), s.end());
LPCWSTR sw = stemp.c_str();
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo;
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = sw;
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;

ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
HANDLE handle = ShExecInfo.hProcess ;
```

//I can now close pdf file 
   TerminateProcess (handle, 0);

My problem is, if acrobat is launched by another process, before my application is launched, TerminateProcess (handle, 0) doesn't do anything.
So how I can get parent handle ?
Thank you